# Looking for a short book on modules

Tags: reference-request, modules

I'm looking for a *short* (100-150 pages) introductory book devoted to the algebra of modules.

(I realize that many comprehensive algebra books include coverage of modules, but I'd prefer to read a more self-contained introductory treatment.)

(A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125476/13675) was asked before, but the two books mentioned among the answers and comments are either too long, and/or not exclusively devoted to modules.)

Comment: Can you read spanish?

Comment: What is your background?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Yes, I can read Spanish well.

Comment: @Potato: I know the basics of groups, rings, and linear algebra.

Comment: @kjo Why not just pick up one of the standard graduate algebra texts then? They all contain a concise treatment of module theory. They also all contain material on fields on Galois theory, which you should also learn.

Comment: @Potato: it's due to a combination of my learning style and my present circumstances; I find it much easier to work with and get more out of short monographs.  I'm sorry I can't give a more illuminating explanation.  I've been studying math on my spare time, on and off, for about 30 years, and have experimented with many approaches, so by now I have a pretty good idea of what works for me, but it's difficult to convey such empirical knowledge.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff which was the book you were going to suggest?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Anillos y sus categorías de representaciones. Cuadernos de Matemática y Mecánica. Instituto de Matemática Aplicada del Litoral, Universidad Nacional del Litoral. Santa Fé, Argentina, 2007.